# Search a string after a match

Tags: command-line, search

Is there any way to search a string after given match ?

e.g. If I run `dmidecode` then it will give a lot of information. e.g.

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: ABCD
    Version: 123456(V1.01)
    Release Date: 01/01/1970
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 8192 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
        Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 1.21
    Firmware Revision: 1.21
```

Now If I grep "version" then it will enlist various matches from `dmidecode` output.
Instead, Is there any way to search for the line "version" right after ^BIOS word and stop at first match ?
So output will be like:

```
Version: 123456(V1.01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo dmidecode |
    awk '/^BIOS/ { ++Bios } Bios && /Version/ { print; exit; }'
    Version: 02PI.M505.20110824.LEO
$
```

We just count that BIOS went past, and trigger on the Version line.

As the BIOS is the first block (on my system), and grep has a max-count option, this should also work

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -m 1 'Version'
```

Comment: Aware of `grep` but do not want to assume that BIOS will be the first block. But `awk` thing works.

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases where you can use `grep -A` to output some lines after your first match, and then re-grep that result

```
dmidecode | grep -A 3 "BIOS Information" | grep "Version"
```

Comment: Here number "3" is fixed. How do I make sure that third line will always be "version"?

Comment: @SHW grep -A 3 actually prints 4 lines: the one that matched, and 3 after. So the second grep relies on there not being more than 2 lines between the BIOS and Version. You could adjust the safety factor. My awk relies on there being a Version somewhere in the block, and only needs one process.

Comment: I don't deny that your version is better. But this version is easier to remember for people with low awk skills :)

Comment: @xenoid I learnt from yours: the -A and -m options were not in my old-school grep (I go back to Solaris 1) so I have always had awk as my go-to, largely because requirements creep can be accommodated, and the source can be commented.